# Why data is not loading from this dispatch action?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to learn redux.

I watch some tutorials and follow along with them. These tutorials are with class component.

So I try to change these into functional component.
Since I am just learning and not trying to make a big project I put actions, reducers and types into 1 file.

This is that file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_NEWS = 'FETCH_NEWS';

// Reducer
const initialState = {
  newsList: [],
};

export const articlesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_NEWS:
      return {...state, newsList: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const fetchNews = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_NEWS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

So I am using `fetchNews` props in `News` component

News component is like this

```
import { fetchNews }from '../../ducks/modules/Articles'
useEffect(() => {
        fetchNews();

        console.log('##############################')
        console.log(newsList)
        console.log('##############################')
},[])
const News = ({navigation, newsList, fetchNews}) => {

return (<View> ....  </View>)
}

News.propTypes = {
    fetchNews: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    newsList: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        newsList: state.articlesReducer.newsList
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchNews })(News);
```

As you can see I am console.logging in the useEffect hooks , I am console logging because no data are being loaded in the device

Here is a picture of empty array when component is mounted [image: Console.log data]

My store component is like this

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  articlesReducer
});


const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk,logger));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not dispatching the action correctly. I have added simpler way to use redux with function based components. You don't need to use `connect`.

```
export const fetchNews = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_NEWS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

export const selectNewsList = (state) => state.newsList; // this is known as a selector.
```

And your view will be:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchNews, selectNewsList }from '../../ducks/modules/Articles'

const News = () => {

const newsList = useSelector(selectNewsList);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchNews());
},[])
console.log(newsList); // This will print empty array first, but will print again as data is populated.
return (<View> ....  </View>)
}
```

Comment: Sadly I follow your guides and its not working yet.
The problem is that The data arrive late I think,
Did my code start rendering at the time of empty array

Comment: Oh it will print empty array in the first run, as `useEffect` will only be run single time when the component gets mounted. The API call is asynchronous and data will arrive late. But that data is available in the redux state, which we can get via selectors. I have updated my answer.